# How can I change the color of selected item in combobox to my custom color in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8-sdk

The selected item color in a combo-box is Green (my phone accent color). How can I change that to a custom color (eg. Yellow)?

Comment: for that you need to customize the combo-box 'style'

Comment: I have customized border colors, selection backgrounds a separate style sheet using blend tool but i don't know where to change the ascent color to my custom color

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use Combobox in Windows Phone

Instaed Use List Picker

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit

Include this library into your references and add this in your xaml

xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

```
<toolkit:ListPicker >
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                 >Your Data Template in Normal Mode
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    Your Data Template in Full Mode
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```